# Отобразить текст как html

Tags: javascript, html, css

Подскажите, пожалуйста, у меня есть небольшой визуальный редактор на js для написания статей.Т.е. есть textarea, а над ним кнопки оформления текста. Есть кнопка добавить html:

```js
$('body').on('click', '.toolbar-html', function(){
    var html = prompt('Введите HTML код', '');
    document.execCommand('insertHTML', false, html);
    return false;
});
```

А как сделать так, чтобы я могла **редактировать** вставленный html код или по другой кнопке перевести текст в html, а потом обратно в обычный вид?

Answer (score 0):

Примитивный пример от меня такой.

```js
let update = document.getElementById("update");
update.addEventListener("click", ()=> {
  let container = document.getElementById("container");
  
  let text = document.getElementById("text");
  container.innerHTML = text.value;
  
  let text1 = document.getElementById("text1");
  text1.value = container.innerHTML;
})
```

```html
<textarea id="text" cols="40" rows="5"><h1>input here html sample and press button</h1></textarea>
<br>
<div id="container">Container</div>
<br>
<button id="update">Update Container</button>
<br>
<textarea id="text1" cols="40" rows="5"></textarea>
```

Comment: не совсем то, в моем случае, уже чистый обычный текст надо перевести в html. Т.е. сделать как у вас, только наоборот.

Comment: У Вас есть только текст? или html? Что у вас в наличии?

Comment: общая картинка такая: в БД хранится оформленный тегами текст, я вывожу его на страницу редактирования в обычном формате (визуально чистый обычный текст). Есть кнопка добавить html, где я записываю текст в тегах, а скрипт добавляет мне чистый обычный текст. Мне нужно, чтобы, например, по кнопке редактировать html, я смогла увидеть не обычный текст,а html разметку и изменить её.

Comment: Ясно щяс решим.

Comment: для примера, как показано в этом реадкторе на кнопке code http://wysibb.com/

Comment: @hellokitViki так вы хотите?

Comment: да, а можно сделать так, чтобы была одна кнопка (тудым-сюдым) и текст менялся сразу в textarea.

Comment: @hellokitViki сделал но так не та уж наглядно